# App compiling but not working in a 2nd generation iPod Touch (4.2.1)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, ipod-touch

I'm working on an app which works fine in an iPhone4. I'm trying to run it in a 2nd generation iPod Touch, but doesn't work, xCode shows a message of "Finished running appName on iPodTouch2" after compilation without errors and warnings.

How can I know the reason it's not working or which framework (AVFoundation, CoreVideo, CoreMedia, AudioToolbox, MediaPlayer, CoreLocation, etc...) is not compatible with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times on this site. But to sum-up: Add `armv6` to device architectures and remove `armv7` from the required device capabilities.

[Here is a link to an answer with screenshots of the steps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8364752/927947)