# Cannot deploy to device, no error message

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am trying to test my app on an ipod (4.2.1) using xcode 4. All worked well in xcode 3. The problem I have right now is when I select my device and click Run, I see "Finish running myapp on myipod", but the app is not installed in the ipod like it used to be. I have spent hours trying to figure out why. I have read many posts and check the provision is install and my device is listed. Still no go. iOS Deployment Target in the Build Settings is set to iOS 4.2. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8364752/927947) for description and screenshots of how to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iPod touch seems to have armv6 CPU. You need to

- add armv6 to Architectures in Build Settings, and
- remove armv7 from Required device capabilities in Info.plist file.